# Replacing non-ASCII quotations from an SQL database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, ascii

I have some text data in an SQL database that consists of weird quotations that appear as `�` on a webpage.

The quotations are these non ascii `”` style quotes instead of the normal `"`

I tried to do

```
$text = str_replace('”', '"', $text);
```

But it seems to have no effect. Does anyone know how I can handle this?

Comment: I found this blog http://shiflett.org/blog/2005/convert-smart-quotes-with-php , it may be helpful for you.

Comment: I smell a utf8 all the way dupe closure coming

Comment: Long Kim - thanks that worked.
mickmackusa - what's that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through